# How to summarize lists in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

to All!

i have this data structure:

```
List[List[String]]
```

all List[String] are the same size, it looks like:

```
List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
```

i need to summarize columns in this lists like this:

```
val result = List(1 + 4 + 7, 2 + 5 + 8, 3 + 6 + 9)
```

with such algorithm

```
res[0] = list1[0] + list2[0] + list3[0]

res[1] = list1[1] + list2[2] + list3[3]
```

...

help, please!

Comment: You talk about list of strings, but in your example you have lists of integers... Which one is it ? In the result, do you need strings like `"1+4+6"` or the result of the computation (`11`) ?

Comment: What have you tried? What is and isn't working? What is the code that you want help with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `transpose` method:

```
scala> val in = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))
in: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9))

scala> in.transpose
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 4, 7), List(2, 5, 8), List(3, 6, 9))

scala> in.transpose.map(_.sum)
res1: List[Int] = List(12, 15, 18)
```